# A variable seems to be de-referencing when I use it in a dynamic array (C++)

Tags: c++, new-operator, dynamic-arrays

Here we are once again good people of the internet.

This is the code I'm using:

```
//This is what is in the header file
int *myArr[]; // A two-dimensional array representing holding the matrix data

//This is what is in the definition file
Matrix::Matrix(int n, int m)
{
    myRows = n;
    myColumns = m;
    initialize();
}

void Matrix::initialize()
{
    *myArr = new int[myRows];

    for (int i=0; i < 3; i++)//Only set to 3 since myRows is acting crazy
    {
        myArr[i] = new int[myColumns];
    }
}
```

For some reason when I use myRows variable to create the myArr array it just seems to stop referencing the value it was pointing towards before.

For instance I give it the value 3 and after the *myArr = new int[myRows] has been executed it changes the value of myRows to 9834496, which I don't understand.

Does the "new" de-reference the variable or something? 
Or am I doing something wrong?

Oh and since this is a school practice project (so I won't blame you if you don't answer) I would prefer an answer over working code, so that I could know what I did wrong for future projects.

Comment: So, the myArr variable is an array of int*?

Comment: The simple, harder to stuff up approach is to use a vector of vectors.  It's still a bit ugly, but much, much better.

Comment: As I understand myArr is a pointer of pointers. But I could be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int *myArr[];
```

This is wrong! You've to tell the compiler the size also, of your array of pointer. How about if you declare `int a[]`. You're telling the compiler to create an array of int, of unknown size, which is not allowed in C++. That is why you cannot do that.

I would suggest you to do this:

```
int **myArr;

void Matrix::initialize()
{
    myArr = new int*[myRows]; //note int* here!

    for (int i=0; i < myRows; i++)
    {
        myArr[i] = new int[myColumns];
    }
}
```

This should work now.

Comment: I think that's wrong too... specifically, `myArr = new int[myRows];` creates a row of `int`, and that may or may not be big enough to store the `int*` values you need in there.

Comment: Ok I got this to work. Although I don't exactly understand why int *myArr[]; is wrong, do I not declare the size using *myArr = new int[myRows]; ?

Comment: @Tony: What are you talking about? Please see my code carefully before commenting. :-)

Comment: But why is int *myArr[]; wrong, it did work (created an array) but the real problem was that it seemed to de-reference the myRows variable.

Comment: @Nawaz: so, you edited during the period where StackOverflow doesn't bother to make a edit history entry?  Clever you....

Comment: @Tony: Yes. Before your comment, I fixed that.

Comment: @Nawaz, why was my original definition wrong? It seemed to work, the problem seemed was that myRows was being changed? (I'm using your solution but I don't understand why it was better or why it fixed my problem.)

Comment: @Siemen: As I said you've to tell the compiler the size also, of your array of pointer. How about if you declare `int a[]`. You're telling the compiler to create an array of int, of unknown size, which is not allowed in C++.

Comment: @Nawaz Ahhhhhh ok. I though I could somehow lock the size of an array later during the execution. I'm guessing since I used new all I did was de-reference the old array and create a new array of a fixed size. But that still doesn't explain why myRow variable changed.

Comment: @Siemen: if your code is not well-formed, then anything could happen with it; that explains why myRow changed its value. theoretically anything can happen; compile the same code with different compiler; you might be see other unexpected behaviour!

Comment: @Nawaz Ok thank you very much I think I'm getting it now. I just returned to C++ after spending some time with C# and I have noticed that C++ makes you work for your program (Not in a bad way) :P

Answer (score 2):

You should use std::vector<>. It deals with all the problems of memory allocation and deallocation.
And it does so without any bugs.

And then you focus yourself on the real goals of your algorithm. Not on memory management :-)

```
typedef std::vector<int> Ints;
typedef std::vector<Ints> Matrix;
Matrix myArray;
```

Comment: Given that this is a school project he/she may have been prohibited from using/wrapping existing containers.  Learning and all that :)

Comment: Yep, but I don't think it is good to be good at multilevel pointers magic. My point of view. And vector is part of the standard c++ library after all ;-)

Comment: I had done a similiar project using vectors, but this project is just as genpfault says. Must use dynamic multi arrays

Comment: @gen @Sie: Then the first course of action is to undo the teachers less-than-intelligent decision to ban a part of C++ and *remake std::vector yourself*. If the teacher wants to do this, that the assignment should have strictly been to remake `std::vector`. So just remake your own `std::vector`, then use it. Anything else is bad practice, and it's a shame teachers feel like they need to encourage bad practice.

Comment: No, the point of this exercise was to re-introduce pointers to people. And he thought this would be a great way to show pointer and multidimensional arrays.

Comment: @Siemsen: Pointers can be learned by implementing `std::vector`, and multi-dimensional arrays are either just nested `std::vector`'s or multi-dimensional access to a single one. The only thing you learn by coding such an obscure piece of work is how to write obscure code, you'd never do that in real code.

Comment: Fair enough. But since I don't choose the projects I'm just gonna do it (I had already done something similar with vectors although I didn't override anything, I hope I don't sound harsh this is just how I type :P).

Comment: @Siemsen, don't worry you don't sound harsh. We just think it is too bad your teacher is focussing too much on pointers ;-). The same amount of hours spent on learning the STL/Standard C++ Library would benefit students much more. ;-). But we are not your teacher ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing:

```
*myArr = new int[myRows];
```

by

```
myArr = new int*[myRows];
```

Comment: That is not enough. His declaration of `myArr` is wrong to start with!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're project requires you to use multi-level pointers, if it doesn't another way you can approach this problem is to just treat the multi-dimensional array as one big flat array.

That means when you reach the end of a row, the index after that would be the first element of the next row. Here's how the code might look:

```
// In this approach the double pointer int**
// is replaced with just a simple int*
int *myArr;

// Here's your Matrix ctor. Note the use of the initializer list
Matrix::Matrix(int n, int m) : myRows(n), myColumns(m)
{
    initialize();
}

void Matrix::initialize()
{
    myArr = new int[myRows * myColumns];

    /* This loop is no longer needed since we're allocating 
       one big chunk at once.
    for (int i=0; i < 3; i++)//Only set to 3 since myRows is acting crazy
    {
      myArr[i] = new int[myColumns];
    }
    */
}

// To retrieve stuff from your array
// you would do something like this:
int Matrix::operator() (const int x, const int y)
{
  return myArr[x * myRows + y];
}
```